# How to send data from AIR to offline SWF using localConnection

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash, localconnection

While the airdata.send('_myConnection', 'myFunction', "myParam");  does work, I can't figure out how to include the domain of SWF since it is local and not uploaded to a server.
I have tried the actual path eg:

c:\work\test.swf

c:\work\test

c:/work/test.swf

//c:/work/test

file:///c:/work/test

(a random generator would probably be useful here... )

like the following, where myPath is one of the above:

airdata.send('myPath:myConnection', 'myFunction', "myParam");

As my ESP abilities are not so much developed to guess what is the magic combination, is there anyone with a greater charisma to help me out?

Comment: The domain is probably `localhost`.

Comment: localhost in place of path doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it does work with localhost in place of path, I just had forgotten the underscore in swfdata.connect("_myConnection"); Thanks.